# TARDIS/Translation/Animals

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

In the episode "A Town Called Mercy" (S07E03 of reboot), the Doctor clearly understands the language of horses.

1) This is the first time in my recollection he is shown to speak with animals.   Is that true?

2) It's my understanding the TARDIS translation works for all species in its vicinity.   This should mean that *everyone* in town can understand the horse(s).  Why is it only the Doctor can?

Comment: My take was that he doesn't speak horse. He's merely pretending to so that he can insult the preacher.

Comment: Also "[Is it the TARDIS that allows the Doctor to speak baby?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/is-it-the-tardis-that-allows-the-doctor-to-speak-baby).

Comment: Later he is shown conversing with the horse (admonishes the horse for cursing).

Comment: Sure, but is there any evidence that the horse understands? No, of course not. Because it's a horse.

Comment: He can talk to humans; how many times has he called humans "apes"?